# how can I access variable outside the function order and use it in another function

Tags: python, session, flask, global-variables

**I want to use newdf outside the function *

*how can I access newdf outside the function order and use it in another function*

```py
   @app.route('/orders', methods=['GET'])
   def order():
     df = pd.read_sql('data_shopify', con=db.engine)
     shop = session.get("shop")
     newdf = df[df.shop == shop]
     print(newdf)
     return redirect('/dash')
```

*the fuction I want to use newdf*

```py
def data()
  return newdf
```

*I have tried using sessions and global varible and they are not working *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python function see the value of global imperative variables like string, integer and can't modify it

to declare a variable and modify it from every function you need to declare
list or dict
like this

```
li = ["hello"]


def first():
    li[0] = "hello world"
    print(li[0]) # hello world

def second():
    print(li[0]) # hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are generally discouraged, but in any case it works fine for me if you declare `newdf` as global whenever you want to modify / assign the value of `newdf`.  For example:

```py
def order():
    global newdf
    newdf = 1
    print(newdf)

def data():
    return newdf

if __name__=='__main__':
    order()
    print(data())
```

Note that you have to declare it as global when you *modify* it, not when you want to *access* it because by that point it's "too late".  You can declare it as global at the beginning of both functions if you like.